# how to check specific field value in controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.3

i have comments function,i have "status" field in comments table 
..i want to check this specific field value if it is equal to 0
or not  in the controller..someone help me please to correct this code

```
   function admin_publish ($id = null){
                  if (!$id) {
                        // set flash message
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid id for Location','default',
array('class' => 'flash_bad'));
                        // redirect
                        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'admin_index'));
                }else{
               // if comment status field 0
        if($comments['Comment']['status']== null){
                // change status from 0 to 1
             $this->Comment->saveField('status',1);
                        // set flash message
                        $this->Session->setFlash('The Comment was successfully
Published.');
                } else {
                     $this->Comment->saveField('status', 0);
                        // set flash message
                        $this->Session->setFlash('The Comment could not be NotPublished.');
                }

                // redirect
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'admin_index'));
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$commentData = $this->Comment->findById($commentId, "Comment.status");
$commentStatus = $commentData["Comment"]["Status"];
if(empty($commentStatus)) {
   //its zero
}
else {
  //its not zero
}
```

Hope it helps